Is it possible to accurately use 3c-4e bonds to describe hypervalency
On Wikipedia, there is a section where it says one way to describe hypercoordination compounds is through using 3c - 4e bonds.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-center_four-electron_bond
It then further goes on to link it to MO theory and NBOs and performs an NBO analysis on the triiodide ions using these 3c-4e bonds. I have seen this very often with pi systems like benzene and ozone and is widely accepted but I haven't seen it much on sigma bonds. There are not many conformations on this nor do many people use this as an explanation for hypercoordination. In this stack exchange question, a user describes that there is no real evidence at all of these.
How can the Bonding in IF7 be explained using LCAO method?
So is it accurate to describe hypervalent compounds like triiodide and xenon difluoride with 3c- 4e bonds to use these bonds to explain their NBOs or are they myths and there is no evidence of them.

A reason for the downvote so I can improve the question is helpful??
